passing params and format to respond_to in rails for downloading file
I am building simple export transactions functionality which onclick download file in csv or json format.
if I do
 <%= link_to "CSV", export_invoices_path(format: :csv), class: link_classes %> |
      <%= link_to "JSON", export_invoices_path(format: :json, start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date]), class: link_classes %>
    

and in controller
  respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data generate_csv(@invoices), filename: "transactions-#{Date.today}.csv" }
      format.json { send_data JSON.pretty_generate(@invoices.as_json), filename: "transactions-#{Date.today}.json" }
    end

it works this way.
but when I replace the view code with the form. page just reloads and no file is downloaded
<%= form_tag export_invoices_path, method: :get, class: "mb-6" do %>
      <div class="flex justify-center gap-2 items-center">
        <p class="font-semibold">Start Date:</p>
        <%= date_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date], class: "form-control" %>
        <p class="font-semibold">End Date:</p>
        <%= date_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date], class: "form-control" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Export to CSV", name: nil, params: { format: :csv }, class: link_classes %>
        <%= submit_tag "Export to JSON", name: nil, params: { format: :json }, class: link_classes %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

I want to use form now cause now I want to pass multiple params such as start_date and end_date to introduce filtering of transactions during export
it should download the file on form submission

Please add the code from your controller to the question. I

Also the logs for the request could be useful.

When you're hitting the button what's happening in your log? Is there request getting to your back end?
If it is not, then you need to debug how the form is constructed.
If it is, then you need to look in the log and see what it's not doing, or if an exception is happening that you're not seeing.

You're using submit_tag like it's a button_to, params: {format: :csv} doesn't work with submit_tag. The only way to do this with submit buttons is to override form action:
<%= form_tag export_invoices_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Export to CSV",
    formaction: export_invoices_path(format: :csv) %>

  <%= submit_tag "Export to JSON", 
    formaction: export_invoices_path(format: :json) %>
<% end %>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#formaction

Unless you do it the old school way by using javascript to change the behavior of the buttons.
